# React native - listview issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

I've ran the react native application I've used the 2 pages both pages are used the listView component but 1 page ran correctly and same functionality  are use in another page but it has return the following error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2UN2.png)

`StaticRenderer.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

page 1 code

```
AsyncStorage.getAllKeys().then((value) => {
        var arr = [];
        for(var i=0;i<value.length;i++){
            if(value[i] != "userName"){
                arr.unshift(value[i]);
            }
        }
        this.setState({
            ds: arr
        })
        this.setState({
            dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.ds),
        })

     }).done();
```

page 2 code

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("userName").then((value) => {
        var data = JSON.parse(value);
        var arr = [];
        if(data != null){
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                arr.unshift(data[i]);
            }
        }
        this.setState({
            ds: arr
        })
        this.setState({
            dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.ds),
        })
     }).done();
```

Page 2 listView

```
<ListView
                        dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
                        renderRow = {this.renderRow.bind(this)}
                        enableEmptySections = {true}>
                    </ListView>
```

Comment: Can you share  your render method ? This code is not clear exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Something's wrong with the `data` you get on page 2.

Is it an array? If so, do you just loop over it and do the `unshift` to make it reverse? If that's the case, you can use `reverse()`.

My guess, though, is that `JSON.parse(value)` returns object. just `console.log` the `arr` variable and see whether it's what the dataSource expects.